# React multiple select with checkbox with more than one option per row

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to have multiple select with checkbox more than one per row? For example, I have four options[a,b,c,d].How to make it 2 options per row, total 2 rows instead of 1 option for 4 rows.

☑a ☑b

☑c ☑d

I tried make it an array =[[a,b],[c,d]], map twice but value will read [a,b],ther outer most value. So when I choose a or b, value will be same [a,b] since code would be some pseudo code like:

```
   <Select
      labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
      id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
      multiple
      value={array}
      onChange={handleChange}
      input={<OutlinedInput label="Tag" />}
      renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(', ')}
      MenuProps={MenuProps}
    >
   array.map((options)=>
       <div value={options}>  <-Value in select will compare value here to check match 
         options.map((option)=>
           <MenuItem key={name} value={option}>  <--this is the value I need
             <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(option) > -1} />
             <ListItemText primary={option} />)
           </MenuItem>
       </div>
   )
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

Check my solution on code-sandbox

[image: Edit quizzical-curie-nhqlh9]

[image: horizontal]

```js
import "./styles.css";
import {
  Select,
  OutlinedInput,
  MenuItem,
  Checkbox,
  ListItemText
} from "@material-ui/core";
export default function App() {
  const array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
  return (
    <>
      <Select
        labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
        id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
        value={array}
        multiple
        style={{ width: "300px", display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}
        input={<OutlinedInput label="Tag" />}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            width: "300px",
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "row",
            flexWrap: "wrap"
          }}
        >
          {array.map((o) => (
            <MenuItem value={o} style={{ width: "150px" }}>
              <Checkbox />
              <ListItemText primary={o} />
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </div>
      </Select>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hello, it shows I need at least 15 reputation to vote. Sorry for that. And I found I can not read selected value, since a div is added for outer most for options map.